# How to filter data from multiple table mapping date range with current date using Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to filter data from joining multiple table and mapping current date with the date range present in the table using `PHP and MySQL`. I am explaining the scenario below.

```
$inputArr=array(array("reg_no"=>"AD17323","college_roll_no"=>"AD1700323","institute_code"=>"AD","full_name"=>"RAJU MALLICK"),array("reg_no"=>"AD17298","college_roll_no"=>"AD1700298","institute_code"=>"AD","full_name"=>"BISWARAJ NAYAK"));
echo json_encode($inputArr);

//[{"reg_no":"AD17323","college_roll_no":"AD1700323","institute_code":"AD","full_name":"RAJU MALLICK"},{"reg_no":"AD17298","college_roll_no":"AD1700298","institute_code":"AD","full_name":"BISWARAJ NAYAK"}]
```

I have the above input array whose value should compare with the multiple table.

> db_application:

```
id      regn_no        exam_code                            Institute_code                            institute_code

1        AD17323     01b1bf82-f206-11e7-a317-005056991fed         AD

2        AD17298     02a1c160-f206-11e7-a317-005056991fed         AD
```

The second table is given below.

> db_app:

```
id       start_date             end_date            exam_code                                       Institute_code         

    1         2018-05-14            2018-05-14           01b1bf82-f206-11e7-a317-005056991fed              AD,BD,MN
```

Here I need to join two table as per the array value in loop and fetch the additional data into array. In array each row has value `reg_no` which will match with column of `regn_no` table `db_application` and the column value of `exam_code and Institute_code` column value should match with second table `i.e-db_app` `exam_code and Institute_code` column value. another condition is the current date should present within `start_date and end_date` and finally the using these condition the value will be filtered from the array. I need to query to filter from  array using these table.

Comment: and no example of what you have tried. You have tried, right?

Comment: Can we get rid of all the PHP stuff for now?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, a sample dataset like the following does nothing to undermine the intent of your question, and I find it much easier to read...

db_application:

```
id regn_no exam_code institute_code 
 1 AD17323 01b1bf82  AD
 2 AD17298 02a1c160  AD

db_app:

id start_date end_date   exam_code institute_code         
 1 2018-05-14 2018-05-14 01b1bf82  AD,BD,MN
```

Now, we can see that you have comma-separated values in your db_app table. This is a mistake. Move these out into a separate, normalised, table.